# Add textarea control dynamically in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Please help me on below requirement with code in angular js,

My page should have an ADD button, when we click on ADD I should add a textarea control. I should be able to add infinite number of textarea controls by clicking this ADD button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this.this is the simplest method: [see](http://plnkr.co/edit/HkY4Zdi06EetTAUsp9nz?p=preview) plunker

html:

```
    <div ng-repeat="textArea in textAreas">
       <textarea id="maxlength_textarea" class="form-control" maxlength="225" rows="2" ng-  model="textArea.textBox" placeholder="textbox"></textarea>

    </div>

<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addMore()">Add More</button>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.textAreas=[];
    $scope.addMore=function(){
    $scope.textAreas.push({textBox:""});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! Need one more help.... if I put an expression 1+2 in any of these textarea, then i should display result of this expression below to this particular textarea.

Comment: Thanks again... we r showing the result while typing, but is there any way to show these results on button click. If we have one more button "Calculate" near to ADD button and onclick of this Calculate button we should be able to show the results.

Comment: I need to add index number before each textarea like Input[0]... I have added a remove button for each textarea. for example, i have added 5 textarea controls, so index will be 0,1,2,3,4. if i remove 3rd index box then index values should be 0,1,2,3. not as 0,1,2,4.

Comment: use ng-repeat="textArea in textAreas track by $index" and use $index as a index.see updated plunker.